# Text Outside of Div

Tags: html, css

For one reason or another, when I attempt to add text to a div, it cleverly misses it.

I'm trying to get the text INSIDE the div, but it's staying outside of it.

Here's a JFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/hspwtyag/1/

```
<div align="center">
<div id="box1">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Rectangle_.png" />
</div>

<div id="box2">
<h2>Proudly celebrating 10 years</h2>
</div>
</div>

* {
 background-image: url("http://images.virtualworldsland.com/blog/2322/796.jpg");
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

#box1 {
 border-radius: 1px solid black;
 width: 500px;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px ;
}

#box2 {
 border-radius: 1px solid black;
 width: 500px;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px ;
 height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**It *is* inside the div** - it's just your background image that's tricking you.

See, if I remove the background image, and change the div's color, the `Proudly celebrating 10 years` can be seen *inside* the red (ie. *inside* the div).

```css
#box1 {
  border-radius: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}
#box2 {
  border-radius: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <div id="box1">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Rectangle_.png" />
  </div>

  <div id="box2">
    <h2>Proudly celebrating 10 years</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So how would I get around this i.e keeping the background and keeping the div white?

Comment: @JugglingBob Change `*` to `body`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you set the background of everything to your image.  Change it to body and you'll be fine.

```
body {
 background-image: url("http://images.virtualworldsland.com/blog/2322/796.jpg");
 background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hspwtyag/2/

Answer (score 0):

You aren't adding the background to the page properly
if you do this it should work:

```
html{
 background-image: url("http://images.virtualworldsland.com/blog/2322/796.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
}

#box1 {
 border-radius: 1px solid black;
 width: 500px;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px ;
 }

#box2 {
 border-radius: 1px solid black;
 width: 500px;
  background: white;
 border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px ;
 height: 150px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hspwtyag/4/)